# Typescript: Merge objects created by Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript

I've an array like this:

```
let aa = [
    Object.defineProperty({alignedType: "t"}, "f1", {value: 1}),
    Object.defineProperty({alignedType: "t"}, "f2", {value: 2}),
    Object.defineProperty({alignedType: "t"}, "f3", {value: 3}),
    Object.defineProperty({alignedType: "t"}, "f4", {value: 4})
];
```

I need to reduce this array an simple object like:

```
let yyy = aa.reduce((acc, e) => {
    return {...acc, ...e};
});
```

I'm running against `yyy` only contains a single object with only `alignedType: "t"`. It has no more properties.

Here you have debugger:

[image]

The object I was expecting is: `{alignedType: "t", f1: 1, f2: 2, f3: 3, f4: 4}`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `{ enumerable: true }` to say that this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object:

```js
let aa = [
  Object.defineProperty({ alignedType: 't' }, 'f1', { value: 1, enumerable: true }),
  Object.defineProperty({ alignedType: 't' }, 'f2', { value: 1, enumerable: true }),
  Object.defineProperty({ alignedType: 't' }, 'f3', { value: 1, enumerable: true }),
  Object.defineProperty({ alignedType: 't' }, 'f4', { value: 1, enumerable: true }),
];


let yyy = aa.reduce((acc, e) => {
  return {...acc, ...e};
});

console.log(yyy);
```

See enumerable on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

**Update**

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax:

The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (stage 4) adds spread properties to object literals. It copies **own enumerable properties** from a provided object onto a new object.